# Prove that $A_f(f)(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly when $r\to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in \mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)$ $2\pi-$periodic and $P_r \in \mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $P_r(y)\geq 0$ ($r\in (0,1]$) such that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(y)dy=1\quad \text{and}\quad \sup_{\delta \leq |x|\leq \pi}P_r(x)\underset{r\to 0}{\to} 0$$
for all $\delta >0$. Let $$\mathcal A(f)(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(y)f(x-y)dy.$$
Prove that $\mathcal A_r(f)(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly when $r\to 0$.

So I have to prove that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|\mathcal A_r(f)(x)-f(x)|\underset{r\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow }f(x).$$

---

**Attempts**

We have $$|\mathcal A_r(f)(x)-f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(y)|f(x-y)-f(x)|dy.$$

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Since $f$ is continuous, there is $\delta $ such that $|f(x-y)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon }{2}$ whenever $|y|<\delta $. Then
$$|\mathcal A_r(f)(x)-f(x)|\leq \underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|y |<\delta }P_r(y)|f(x-y)-f(x)|dy}_{=I}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|y|\geq |\delta |}P_r(y)|f(x-y)-f(x)|dy}_{=J}.$$

Now, $$I\leq \frac{\varepsilon }{2}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(y)dy=\frac{\varepsilon }{2}.$$ and $$J\leq K\sup_{\delta \leq |y|\leq \pi}P_r(y),$$
where $K$ is independent of $x$.

At the end $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|\mathcal A_r(f)(x)-f(x)|\leq \frac{\varepsilon }{2}+K\sup_{\delta \leq |y|\leq \pi}P_r(y)\to \frac{\varepsilon }{2},$$

and thus the convergence is uniform.

---

**Question :** What is wrong in what I did ? I had that at a practice exam, it's what I did and I only had a grade of $5/10$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in what you wrote, $\delta $ depend on $x$. To be more clear, I'll write $\delta _x$ instead of $\delta $ and $I_{\delta _x}$ and $J_{\delta _x}$ instead of $I$ and $J$. Nevertheless, it's true that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}I_{\delta _x}\leq \frac{\varepsilon }{2},$$
but unfortunately, you don't have a uniform bound for $J_{\delta _x}$ since $\sup_{\delta _x\leq |y|\leq \pi}P_r(y)$ depend on $x$. However, remark that using the $2\pi-$periodicity of $f$, $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|\mathcal A_r(f)(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in[-\pi,\pi]}|\mathcal A_r(f)(x)-f(x)|,$$
and thus, if $\varepsilon >0$ is fixed, by uniform continuity of $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, there is $\delta =\delta (\varepsilon )>0$ s.t. $|f(x-y)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon }{2}$ whenever $|y|< \delta$. And here, $\delta$ doesn't depend on $x$. Now, you can do what you did, and the claim will indeed follow.

Comment: Oh, god ! you are completely write ! I would never remark this detail. Very nice remarked, congratulation. (+1). Do you think that my grade of 5/10 is a bit strict ? Because all the rest I did was fine...

Comment: *"Very nice remarked, congratulation."* : Actually, It's a classical mistakes. When you are trained to see this kind of mistakes, it's quite obvious. *"Do you think that my grade of 5/10 is a bit strict ?"* It depends on the expectation of the corrector. I think it's a bit strict... something as 7/10 would have been more reasonable if there were no other mistakes. But you probably made other small mistakes that can justify a $5$. But why don't you ask directly to the corrector ?